# iOS 8: blank gap at bottom of full screen Safari home screen page

Tags: javascript, html, ios8, fullscreen, statusbar

Please forgive any breaches of protocol and correct me if need be: long-time reader, first-time poster here. I could not find any solutions online that worked or were terribly recent and I was wondering if anyone else had encountered this.

I've been enabling full screen on a web page with meta tags and adding a shortcut to the home screen. I recently upgraded to iOS 8.0.2 on an iPad Air and have noticed that the status bar information (iPad, Wifi, Clock, battery, lock) are now on top of the top edge of the website window instead of over an unusable black status bar. As well, there seems to be white dead space now at the bottom of the page, probably displacing the now non-existent status bar.

Does anyone know how I can either revert back to having the status bar or use the bottom part of the page using javascript?

Many thanks for any help you can provide. I've attached some screen shots and some brief code below.

Cheers,
Kurt

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-touch-fullscreen" content="yes">
    <meta id="extViewportMeta" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  </head>
    <title>Full Screen</title>
  <style>
  body {
    background: #0000FF;
    font-size: 140pt;
  }
  </style>
  <body>
    A<br />B<br />C<br />D<br />E<br />F<br />G<br />H
  </body>
</html>
```

Images here:
http://postimg.org/gallery/2cm224s78/

Comment: You should close your head tag!

Comment: Oops, I guess I cut it out when I was paring down my code to demonstrate the issue. Thanks for the heads up. I've altered it, however the problem remains.

Comment: This is a bug in 8.0.2. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25884806/ios-8-web-app-status-bar-position-and-resizing-problems

Comment: <title> goes within the <head> tags

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem and found this little gem of a fix...just put it in the head of your document ::

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent"/>
```

[iOS 8 status bar overlay + footer 'bar' in HomeScreen web applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26221394/ios-8-status-bar-overlay-footer-bar-in-homescreen-web-applications/26307791#26307791)