# Apple mobile status bar behaves different on two iOS 8 iPads

Tags: ipad, ios8, fullscreen, statusbar

I have two iPads that I'm developing on. One is an iPad air, the other is an iPad Retina 4th Gen. When I upgraded to iOS 8.1 on both, my web app was showing the status bar at the bottom. So I added the following code from [iOS 8: web app status bar position and resizing problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25884806/ios-8-web-app-status-bar-position-and-resizing-problems):

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black"/>
```

This fixed the problem on my iPad Air. But the retina device was showing a black status bar. So, I tried this:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent"/>
```

This fixed the issue on the retina device, but now my iPad air is showing a narrow black bar at the bottom of the screen (see images).

Why is there a difference between these devices, both on iOS 8? How do I find a solution for both? Do I detect the device model and add corresponding lines using if else? Is there a more elegant way?

Users are using iPad 4 right now, but could upgrade any time, causing a mix of Airs and 4s. So I need a solution that works on both. Also, this is a web app built on JavaScript and AngularJS + HTML5. 
[image: iPad air UI]

[image: iPad Retina UI]

Comment: i think you should check if user is using ipad air or ipad 4th gen.
Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448162/determine-device-iphone-ipod-touch-with-iphone-sdk/1561920#1561920

Comment: Users are using iPad 4 right now, but could upgrade any time, causing a mix of Airs and 4s. So I need a solution that works on both. Also, I should've mentioned, this is a webapp built on JavaScript and AngularJS + HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove and re-add your webapp to your home screen after setting the status bar to "black-translucent"